# Hide hairs below a hat

Tags: particles, hair, boolean-modifier

how can I hide the hairs of a character wearing a hat?

I tried to convert them to mesh and then applying a boolean, but the boolean modifier often returns weird results, and this is one of them.

I hear about the `Vertex Weight Proximity Modifier`, but I honestly don't understand how to use it with the hair emitters.

The character has multiple hair emitters, to simulate the various hair variations.

Thank you!

[image: picture]

Comment: you can use the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier to control the length and density of the hair. It can work with a short hair style. But I don't think it will help you with this kind of long hair style. I've seen in games they just use a different hair style that fits when the character wears a hat.

Comment: In Blender 3.5, there is a shrinkwrap modifier/node group that can shrink-wrap the new hair curves to a surface. Maybe you can combine that with a proximity modifier. Just an idea, I don't know if this works.

Comment: @Blunder thanks for the idea, I will check it out